how to query dynamo db with date and additional attribute as a sort key?
I have a product table in DynamoDB, with product id as a primary key and date as a range key. I plan to query the products that were entered in the system in specified date, so planning to use that as a range key.
I would also like to query based other category of the products they fall under, so
can my range key be something like this
range key = category-date, this way I can query all the product that falls under some category and then sorted by date? if yes, can I store directly as a string , "clothing-2024-07-27" , I know for dynamo db, this is just a string as there is no date time format . so what would be the best option here, if I want to query based on date and one more attribute?
id         |     date       |   category      | quantity
----------------------------------------------------------
1          | 2024-08-28     | electronics     |   20 
3          | 2024-07-27     | clothing        |   10 
2          | 2024-06-26     | furniture       |   15 
...


resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "product" {
 name = "product"
 billing_mode = "PROVISIONED"
 read_capacity = 10
 write_capacity = 5

 hash_key = "productId"
 range_key  = "date"

  attribute {
    name = "productId"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "date"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "category"
    type = "S"
  }

 tags = {
   Name = "Product"
 }
}


Having date as a sort key on the table doesn't help.  In fact it hurts as you can't GetItem() unless you know both the product ID and the date it was added;


Use a Global Secondary Index (GSI)
Instead of modifying the range key, you can create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) to support querying by category. This way, you keep the primary key structure intact and add the ability to query by category efficiently.
Table Structure:
Primary Key: productId (Hash Key)
Range Key: date (Sort Key)
GSI Structure:
GSI Hash Key: category
GSI Range Key: date
Example Table Definition with GSI
Here’s how you can define your DynamoDB table with a GSI:

  resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "product" {
  name           = "product"
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = 10
  write_capacity = 5

  hash_key = "productId"
  range_key  = "date"

  attribute {
    name = "productId"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "date"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "category"
    type = "S"
  }

  global_secondary_index {
    name               = "CategoryDateIndex"
    hash_key           = "category"
    range_key          = "date"
    read_capacity      = 5
    write_capacity     = 5
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "ProductTable"
  }
}

Above approach will help you.

thanks. I haven't created the table yet ,but is this secondary index, something I can add later, just in case requirements change?
